# Python Pandas calculate time until output reaches 0

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in python with several columns and a datetime stamp. One of the columns has a true/false variable. I'd like to calculate time until that column is false.

Ideally it would look something like this:

```
datetime             delivered    secondsuntilfailure
2014-05-01 01:00:00    True       3
2014-05-01 01:00:01    True       2
2014-05-01 01:00:02    True       1
2014-05-01 01:00:03    False      0
2014-05-01 01:00:04    True       ?
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried something? Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can first change order by `[::-1]`, then find [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) and count [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) if values are `True`:

```
df = df[::-1]
print (df.datetime.diff().astype('timedelta64[s]'))
4    NaN
3   -1.0
2   -1.0
1   -1.0
0   -1.0
Name: datetime, dtype: float64

df['new'] = df.delivered.where(~df.delivered,df.datetime.diff().astype('timedelta64[s]'))
              .cumsum().fillna(0).astype(int).mul(-1)
df = df[::-1]
print (df)
             datetime delivered secondsuntilfailure  new
0 2014-05-01 01:00:00      True                   3    3
1 2014-05-01 01:00:01      True                   2    2
2 2014-05-01 01:00:02      True                   1    1
3 2014-05-01 01:00:03     False                   0    0
4 2014-05-01 01:00:04      True                   ?    0
```

Comment: I get the following error: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-d0bf920f0cb1> in <module>()
      4 
      5 
----> 6 df['new'] = df.Pffr_deliverysuccess.where(~df.Pffr_deliverysuccess,df.DateTime.diff().astype('timedelta64[s]')).cumsum().fillna(0).astype(int).mul(-1)
      7 df = df[::-1]
      8 print (df)

Comment: C:\Users\caljrr\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in __invert__(self)
    780     def __invert__(self):
    781         try:
--> 782             arr = operator.inv(_values_from_object(self))
    783             return self.__array_wrap__(arr)
    784         except:

TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Comment: the column name is actually Pffr_deliverysuccess not delivered

Comment: Sorry, I think `~df.Pffr_deliverysuccess`

Answer (score 0):

Count the seconds:

```
cumsecs = df.datetime.diff().astype('timedelta64[s]').cumsum().fillna(value=0.0)
```

Copy the cumulative value whenever delivered fails, and fill any preceeding values:

```
undeliv_secs = cumsecs.where(~df['delivered']).fillna(method='bfill')
```

Seconds until failure is just the difference between the two:

```
df['secondsuntilfailure'] = undeliv_secs - cumsecs
print(df)
             datetime delivered  secondsuntilfailure
0 2014-05-01 01:00:00      True                  3.0
1 2014-05-01 01:00:01      True                  2.0
2 2014-05-01 01:00:02      True                  1.0
3 2014-05-01 01:00:03     False                  0.0
4 2014-05-01 01:00:04      True                  NaN
```

Comment: I get the following error: ypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-18a0402f63f3> in <module>()
      1 
      2 cumsecs = df.DateTime.diff().astype('timedelta64[s]').cumsum().fillna(value=0.0)
----> 3 undeliv_secs = cumsecs.where(~df['Pffr_deliverysuccess']).fillna(method='bfill')
      4 df['Duration'] = undeliv_secs - cumsecs

Comment: C:\Users\caljrr\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in __invert__(self)
    780     def __invert__(self):
    781         try:
--> 782             arr = operator.inv(_values_from_object(self))
    783             return self.__array_wrap__(arr)
    784         except:

TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Comment: It sounds like your Pffr_deliverysuccess is a float. You should make a new column where it is converted to bool and use that in the where()